# How to see previous –next image option in the theme?

Tags: images, pagination

I could see previous –next image option  in the default Twenty Sixteen theme even without installation any plugins.

But I would like  to use Big Blue theme instead of default one and I could not see previous –next image option  regardless that I’ve installed different plugins related gallery like Gallery Portfolio, NextGEN Gallery, PB SEO Friendly Images……

What need to be done to see  previous –next image option   in Big Blue or any other (not only default ) themes?

Thanks.

//Edited
//single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package Big Blue
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header article-header <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){echo 'featured-image'; } ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'single-post-thumbnail' ) ); ?>
        <div class="blue-overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="entry-detail">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                <?php $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', esc_html__( ', ', 'big-blue' ) ); ?>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php big_blue_posted_on(); ?> 
                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <?php
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single');

                                the_post_navigation();

                                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                                    comments_template();
                                endif;

                            endwhile; // End of the loop.
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: What is previous –next image option? Where you can see it? In admin page or website front? Attach the screenshot of these options if you can, please

Comment: Near photo, i cold see this clickable option  next - previous..
How to attach screenshot here?

Answer (score 0):

You should insert post navigation manually.

Update functions.php of your theme with

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content) {
  return $content . get_the_post_navigation();
});
```

Or insert the_post_navigation() in desirable place in your single.php template.

You should create [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to be able update primary theme.

Comment: I could add_filter to  functions.php but creating  child theme seems pretty  advanced....never done it. ...  Also, I've already modified this theme and need to do something even more complicate  to get navigation :)
I added a single.php.  Could you specify the direction that i could follow to get navigation in Big Blue theme?

Comment: I could navigate between galleries using your add_filter() but I could not still navigate between photos themselves...  Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Adding function dd_filter in function.php file  allow to navigate only between galleries but not between photos themselves.

Also, navigation direction  were in the place of images and  in order to see navigation, I need to delete some images.

Obviously, it is not the right way to do.

S0. I find some themes where the navigation  was already installed  and used those themes.

One of those theme is default theme that was mentioned in the original post.